# Accessing meteor application's imports directory from a package?

Tags: javascript, meteor, module, package, ecmascript-6

Meteor application directory layout:

```
imports/
  api/
    collections/
      MyCollectionFile.js

packages/
  mypackage/
      mypackageMain.js
```

I can export anything from the package file and use it inside the application, that's ok. But how can I use "import" in the package, like the other way around?

```
// mypackageMain.js
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    require ('/imports/api/collections/MyCollectionFile.js');
};
```

**OR**

```
import '/imports/api/collections/MyCollectionFile.js';
```

I tried using the path *'../../imports/api/collections/MyCollectionFile.js'* but it simply does not work. I can not access this file from a package.

I get the following Error for both the import and the require:

```
W20160618-23:25:59.486(3)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module '../../imports/api/collections/MyCollectionFile.js'
W20160618-23:25:59.487(3)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:85:1)
```

Comment: This kind of goes against the principle of packages being self-contained. You can export from your package a function that accepts some symbol from you application instead of trying to import it from the package. It makes it more portable.

Comment: @MasterAM you are right. It's a safety measure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that this was not possible.

However, moving the collections to a package and exporting them would make the collections available to other packages and the application.

Answer (score 1):

I've also been running in to this issue and have found two solutions, both are sub-par though.

1. Install the thing you want to import as a npm package. `$npm install --save ./imports/<the thing>`.
2. Use `npm link` to create a link to the thing you want to import.

Both solutions require that you have a `package.json` in the directory you want to import and both won't be transpile the code and just run it against the provided version of node.

A possible solution for the transpile issue would be using a loader plugin, or somehow provide a additional configuration to System.js to tell it to transpile the code on import.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But that seems quite like an overkill to me :)